# Basic HTML CSS. Why my CSS on Button does not work?

Tags: html, css

I'm making mock up site to learn. But my css on Buttons don't work, I can put any css and their appearance doesn't change.

HTML:

```
<div id="bottom">
    <form method="get">
        <button class="sButtons" type="submit" name="gSearch">Google Search</button>
       <button class="sButtons" type="submit" name="gLucky">I'm Feeling Lucky!</button>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
#sButtons{
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0 7px;
    width: 100px; 
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color:black;
}
```

(I just put very random values into it just to see if there's a difference)

here's a link to the rest of my code https://gist.github.com/Bitvala/4c0600c03c3a215fd023

Comment: `#` is for `ids`. `.` is for `classes`.

Comment: Classes begin with a period, IDs, with a hash. So use `.sButtons`.

Comment: `.sButtons` will do the trick!

Comment: What is your learning material? Where did you learn how to use CSS?

Comment: Such a silly mistake. Not really helpful in future for anyone.you should better close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS the Class selector is defined with a dot like so:

```
.Divclass{
    position:absolute;
}
```

And the ID Selector is used with a #, like so:

```
#DivID{
    position:absolute;
}
```

What you want to do is:

```
.sButtons{
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0 7px;
    width: 100px; 
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `#sButtons` to `.sButtons`

or `class` to `id`